# Como comparar a estrutura de duas tabelas e atualizar a outra?

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados

A pergunta é a mesma do título:

Como comparar a estrutura de duas tabelas e atualizar a outra?

Tenho um banco de dados online, o qual pretendo atualizar a estrutura do mesmo. Tenho também alguns clientes que usam bancos dedados offline em suas máquinas.

Quero que, quando meu cliente tiver internet, ele compare a estrutura do banco dele com a do banco online. Caso haja diferença, ele atualize.

Comment: A diferença é apenas estrutural ou de dados inseridos no banco de dados?

Comment: diferença estrutural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá pra fazer através do Workbench do MySql:

Primeiro, você tem que converter seu schema em um model, faça assim:

1. Database > Reverse Engineer
2. Selecione o banco de dados > Next
3. Next
4. Selecione o schema que quer converter > Next
5. Next
6. Selecione as tabelas > Execute >
7. Next
8. Finish

Após ter convertido o schema em model, faça:

1. Database > Synchronize with Any Source
2. Next
3. Send Updates To > Destination Database Server > Next
4. Preencha os dados do Banco Alvo > Next
5. Next
6. Selecione a tabela que quer sincronizar > Next
7. Next
8. Serão listadas todas as alterações disponíveis > Next
9. Execute >

Será gerado um txt com as alterações possíveis e ao clicar em `Execute >` ele irá executar todas as alterações e deixar as estruturas dos dois bancos idênticas.

Caso tenha algum erro, será listado também.